# Running MongoDB dictionary-based commands through ObjCMongoDB

Tags: ios, mongodb, swift, objcmongodb

Other commands work correctly for me, such as:

```
let commandDictionary = ["count": "trials"]
let error: NSError?
let result = myConnection.runCommandWithDictionary(
    commandDictionary, 
    onDatabaseName: databaseName, 
    error: &error
)
```

Attempting a `distinct` command doesn't, though:

```
let commandDictionary = ["distinct": "trials", "key": "location"]
let error: NSError?
let result = myConnection.runCommandWithDictionary(
    commandDictionary, 
    onDatabaseName: databaseName, 
    error: &error
)
```

After running this, the value of `error` is: `Optional("MONGO_COMMAND_FAILED: The command returned with \'ok\' value of 0")`. Running what (I believe) is the same command in the shell gives me sane values:

`db.runCommand({distinct: "trials", key: "location"})`

#### Update #1:

Also, `MongoConnection.serverVersion()` gives me: `"2.6.3"`, and `MongoConnection.serverError()` returns `nil`. The verbose server logs show this when running the command in the shell:

`2014-12-12T10:11:54.556-0500 [conn69] command eim.$cmd command: distinct { distinct: "trials", key: "metadata.location" } keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) r:606 reslen:210 0ms`

And they show this for the command as run by ObjCMongoDb:

`2014-12-12T10:10:25.945-0500 [conn171] command eim.$cmd command: isMaster { key: "metadata.location", distinct: "trials" } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0  reslen:138 0ms`

#### Update #2:

It seems that somewhere the `distinct` command is getting mapped to the `isMaster` command. This happens for other commands. For instance, the command `{listDatabases:1}` is mapped to `isMaster`, as well. However, the command `{buildInfo:1}` is correctly mapped to `buildInfo`.

Comment: Seems like you're doing it right. MongoConnection+Diagnostics has a `-serverVersion` method. What does it return?

Comment: Is what you're printing there the value of `error`? Does `-[connection serverError]` give you anything useful?

Comment: Yes, that's the value of `error`. Will edit to make that clear.

Comment: `MongoConnection.serverVersion()` gives me: `"2.6.3"`, and `MongoConnection.serverError()` returns `nil` every time.

Comment: Strange. I can't reproduce it, I haven't tried in Swift but I have equivalent Objective-C code that works fine. Are you using replication? Have you tried it in Objective-C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in this [issue report](https://github.com/paulmelnikow/ObjCMongoDB/issues/16), the problem is that the database requires the keys to be in order, but Swift, like Objective-C, doesn't preserve the order of dictionary keys.

As author of the library, my suggested workaround is to construct the command using OrderedDictionary, which is included with the library.

**Update:**

In version 0.12.0 of the library, -runCommandWithDictionary is deprecated. Here's code for the new method:

```
let error: NSError?
let result = myConnection.runCommandWithName(
    "distinct", 
    value: "trials",
    arguments: ["key": "location"],
    onDatabaseName: databaseName, 
    error: &error
)
```